# PHP array not instantiated

Tags: php

```
<?php
class Validate{
    private $_passed = false,
            $_errors = array(),
            $_db = null;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->_db=DB::getInstance();
    }

    public function check($source,$items = array()){
        foreach($items as $item=>$rules){
            foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value){

                $value = $source[$item];

                if($rule == 'required' && empty($value)){
                    $this->addError("{$item} is required");
                }else
                {

                }

            }

        }
        if($this->$_errors){ # <-- line 27
            $this->$_passed=true;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->$_passed=false;
        }
    }

    private function addError($error){
        $this->$_errors[] = $error; # <-- line 37

    }
    public function errors(){
        return $this->$_errors;
    }
    public function passed(){
        return $this->$_passed;
    }
}
```

I am getting an error on line 37 that is:

> Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading.

If `addError($error)` is not called then on line 27 I get:

> Notice: Undefined variable: _errors
>
> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property

Comment: Use `array_push` instead? `array_push($this->$_errors, $error);`.

Comment: I still get variable undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using JavaScript variable declaration, you should change it to

```
private $_passed = false;
private $_errors = array();
private $_db     = null;
```

Then when you assign a new item to the array, drop the `$`

```
$this->$_errors[] = $error;
```

Becomes

```
$this->_errors[] = $error;
```